# Why Symfony4 annotations not work in my mac?

Tags: annotations, symfony4

I installed Symfony4 using the following steps.

step1: composer create-project "Symfony/skeleton:^4.0” symfony4
step2: git status
step3: git add.
step4: git commit
step5: composer require annotations
step6: create a controller named ArticleController

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ArticleController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
       return new Response('OMG! My first page already! Wooooo!');
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
    */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        echo 123;die;
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/news/{$slug}")
    * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
    */
    public function news($slug)
    {
        return new Response(sprintf('Today new is "%s"', $slug));
    }
}
```

Step7: access http://127.0.0.1:8000
You can view 'OMG! My first page already! Wooooo!'.

But http://127.0.0.1:8000/123 and http://127.0.0.1:8000/news/test do not work. Who can tell me why? And please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the solution.

composer require symfony/apache-pack

It will automatically generate .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

the right namespace is :

```html
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
```

thanks